# Only take up space on printed receipt if a row in a portal has a value in FileMaker

Tags: filemaker, portal

**What I'm trying to do:**
Print out a report that's a lists orders for a customer with a "grand total" that displays about 1 inch below the last order...whether there be 1 row, 4 rows, 10 rows, etc.

**What I've done:**
I have a "Customers" table and a related "Orders" table.

I created a layout (based on the "Customers" table) that will be a report I print.

I have inserted a portal to display orders and had to choose the maximum number of rows.

**My question:**
How do I ensure that the "grand total" will appear an inch below the last row in the Orders portal and not at the same spot on the page no matter how many orders?  Right now, since I selected the number of rows in the portal as 10, someone that has 1 order will have a printout that has the one order but then a lot of whitespace before the "grand total" appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Portals are not print-friendly. Print your report from the Orders table, and use sub-summary parts to show customer data and sub-total.

Comment: Great to know!  I'll go that route.